# Is it possible to enter a New Line in a string without Escape Sequences?

Tags: c#, string, escaping, ascii

I want a `String` to have a `New Line` in it, but I cannot use escape sequences because the interface I am sending my string to does not recognize them.  As far as I know, C# does not actually store a `New Line` in the `String`, but rather it stores the escape sequence, causing the literal contents to be passed, rather than what they actually mean.

My best guess is that I would have to somehow parse the number 10 (the decimal value of a `New Line` according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)) into ASCII.  But I'm not sure how to do that, because C# parses numbers directly to `String` if attempting this:

```
"hello" + 10 + "world"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What interface are you using? You may need to write methods that convert between a C# string and your other systems interpretation of a string and how they handle newline. Apples and Oranges and all that!

Comment: Can you describe the interface and how you are sending the string to it?

Comment: It's a languange written for motion control by my company, and I'm writing tests for it using a .NET library we have and NUNIT.  I'm just passing strings over that are then read in as commands.  Essentially, I want to set a string variable in this interface, and then retrieve it, making sure that the string was not cut off by detecting a new line character

Comment: Then why are you sending newlines to it? Does it require them to Action the command? Do you need to send newlines?

Comment: @Belogix Just clarified, sorry.

Comment: `\n` is just a byte sequence. If your system doesn't recognize the bytes or throws them out then you'll need another avenue.

Comment: @Nealon - Okay but WHY are you sending newline in the first place? What would you expect the controller to do when it receives it? Are you trying to write a byte stream and using a string instead? What is the end goal you are after rather than what you are doing?

Comment: @Belogix I want users to be able to retrieve any string they might have in their variable, including if they wanted to put newlines in that variable.  I just want to make sure that the system doesn't read the new line as the end of the string (which it shouldnt because it should wait for a null).  Just want to check things thoroughly.  Essentially: I expect the controller to ignore it.

Comment: Well, the controller obviously isn't ignoring it so unless you are writing the controller code then I think you will have to strip them out before passing down?

Comment: I'm still lost in this part of your statement: `I cannot use escape sequences because the interface I am sending my string to does not recognize them.`.  If it doesn't do you want it to?  If not, then you're done.  If so, then define the sequence it _does want_.  Other than that something's missing in your description of the goal.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I want it to recognize that there is a new line in the string, but it doesnt know that \n is a new line

Comment: @Belogix Not ignore the string entirely, what I expect to get back when I retrieve the variable is the full string with the new line in it.  What I am afraid of getting is the string up to the new line, and nothing after

Comment: Then again:  define what it _does want_.  You proposed ASCII 10, which translates in C# as `\n` or `Environment.NewLine`.  So I assume then that this is C++ style, `\r\n` that you really want...a pair consisting of ASCII 13 and 10.

Comment: @DonBoitnott using more escape sequences fixes nothing if my controller doesnt know what an escape sequence is.

Comment: The literal escape sequence is not part of the `string` in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say `"hello\nworld"`, the actual string will contain:

```
hello
world
```

There will be an actual new-line character in the string. At no point are the characters `\` and `n` stored in the string.

There are a few ways to get the exact same result, but a simple `\n` in the string is a common way.

A simple cast should also do the same:

```
"hello" + (char)10 + "world"
```

Although likely slightly slower because of string concatenation. I say "likely" because it could probably be optimized away, or an actual example using `\n` will also result in string concatenation, taking roughly the same amount of time.

[Test](https://ideone.com/cOHsAx).

Comment: Can this be confirmed?  If that's true than my question has no point, just from looking at what was getting passed, it appeared that `\n\ was being passed, and not a `new line`

Comment: @Nealon You're seeing a debug representation.  It's visual only.  The string is in memory, as described.

Comment: I will try to confirm this myself to make sure it is working, if so, thats all I needed to understand, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The preferred new line character is `Environment.NewLine` for its cross-platform capability.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xml for communication, if you're receiver can handle this